# Control Structures- why is switch and goto not in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, documentation

I was surprised to not see this question here already, and I've either missed the explanation in the docs or it's just not there. It's appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Here's an answer on [why goto is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solidity isn't Javascript. [Neither of them are there](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=goto#control-structures).

`switch` offers nothing more than a convenient `if...else` shortcut. I don't know why it wan't implemented in Solidity.

Admittedly subjective, but I've never worked anywhere that didn't explicitly outlaw `goto` as a bad idea. (Have a read of the infamous 1968(!) "[A Case against the GO TO Statement](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF)".) In an arena where defensive coding is particularly important, `goto` isn't something that would be considered good practice.

Comment: Using switch instead of a large if-else tree can make optimization easier for compilers, because a switch can be directly converted into a branch table.

Comment: Although I completely agree that goto should generally be avoided, I'm not sure why JavaScript is brought up in your answer, since JavaScript doesn't (natively) support goto neither AFAIK. Surely you can implement goto functionality easily with JavaScript, but that's the case for all languages with metaprogramming capabilities, and metaprogramming is not a bad thing, albiet for a contract oriented language such as solidity, metaprogramming capabilities may be undesirable and should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `goto` in Solidity but you can somewhat emulate it using the `break` and `continue` statements, which compile directly to jump instructions.

- `break` jumps to the code right after the current innermost loop.
- `continue` jumps to the start of the current innermost loop.

To jump forwards you can `break` out of a `do ... while(false);` loop like this:

```
do
{
    // Code here is always executed
    if (a) break; // if (a) goto label1;
    // Code here is skipped if a evaluated to true.
}
while (false);
// label1:
```

To jump backwards you can `continue` in a `while(true) { ... break; }` loop:

```
// label2:
while (true)
{
    // Code here is executed at least once, and repeats while a is true.
    if (a) continue; // if (a) goto label2;
    // Code here is only executed once.
    break;
}
```

Of course this is not recommended at all :)

Comment: This doesn't work in cases where the gotos and the labels intersect. a: if (something) goto b; c; b: if(something) goto c;